When build glibc, it has err "No rule to make target '/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/build/assert/stamp.os'"
echo "/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/dist/lib "    \
| gawk -f gen-trusted-dirs.awk > /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/build/elf/trusted-dirs.T;
echo '' > /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/build/elf/stamp.oST
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/build/assert/stamp.os', needed by '/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/build/libc_pic.a'.  Stop.

I download glibc 2.28 from github, following is my build.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status
set -e
# Get the directory of the script (Project Directory)
PROJECT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
# Define variables
GLIBC_SRC_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR" # Set the source directory to the project directory
DIST_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR/dist"
BUILD_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR/build"
# Create the build directory
if [ -d "$BUILD_DIR" ]; then
echo "Cleaning up previous build directory..."
rm -rf "$BUILD_DIR"
fi
mkdir "$BUILD_DIR"
cd "$BUILD_DIR"
# Configure the build
echo "Configuring the build..."
../configure --prefix="$DIST_DIR"
# Compile glibc
echo "Compiling glibc..."
make -j$(nproc) # Use all available CPU cores
# Install glibc to the specified dist directory
echo "Installing glibc to $DIST_DIR..."
make install
# Cleanup
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
echo "Cleaning up build files..."
rm -rf "$BUILD_DIR"
# Output instructions for setting up the environment variables
echo -e "\nglibc has been successfully installed to $DIST_DIR."
# Instructions for setting up environment variables
echo -e "\nTo use this glibc globally, add the following to your shell profile (e.g., ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc):\n"
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIST_DIR/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
echo -e "\nFor immediate effect, run the following command:\n"
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIST_DIR/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"a


I find the reason, it's dropbox sync err
in build dir exist
~/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28 $ lsa /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/glibc-glibc-2.28/build/elf/stamp
stamp (Case Conflict).os  stamp.o                   stamp.oS

dropbox auto rename stamp.os to stamp (Case Conflict).os, so don't compile glibc in dropbox sync dir fix it
